# Groups of order 56 with Sylow 2-subgroup isomorphic $Q_8$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product

I try to classify non-abelian groups of order $56$ with sylow $2$-subgroup isomorphic to quaterion group $Q_8$. More accurately I want to construct $2$ non-isomorphic such groups. This is an excercise 5.3.7 from Dummit and Foote's book.
 I can construct such groups  as semidirect product as follows
$G_1 = C_7 \rtimes_{\phi_{1}} Q_8$, $G_2 = C_7 \rtimes_{\phi_{2}} Q_8$, $G_3 = C_7 \rtimes_{\phi_{3}} Q_8$, where $\phi_n: Q_8 \to \operatorname{Aut}(C_7)$. 
Let $Q_8 = <i,j>$ and $<\sigma>$ be  a unique subgroup of order $2$ of $\operatorname{Aut}(C_7) \cong C_6$,  where $\sigma$ inverts elements of $C_7$. We define 
$\phi_1$ as 
$$\phi_1(i) = \sigma, \phi_1(j) = \operatorname{id}$$ 
(here $\operatorname{id}$ is an identical automorphism), 
$$\phi_2(i) = \operatorname{id}, \phi_2(j) = \sigma$$ 
and
$$\phi_3(i) = \sigma, \phi_3(j) = \sigma$$

> My question. Am I right that all this groups are isomorphic? And if all this groups are isomorphic what is the second type of such gruops?

I use the following result about isomorphism of semidirect product. Let $\tau\in \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ than $N\rtimes_{\phi} H \cong N\rtimes_{\tau\phi} H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: those are all isomorphic.  The second type is of course the direct product.  That is different as $C_7$ is central in the direct product of $C_7$ with $Q_8$.

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason I do not know why I thought that we should construct precisely non-trivial homomorphisms =)